# How to record array of ints, and print frequency of duplicates

Tags: java, arrays

Note:  Just a practice problem, not for marks.

This is a practice problem given in a first year Java course:

> Design and implement an application that reads an arbitrary number of integers, by the user, that are in the range 0 to 50 inclusive, and counts how many occurrences of each are entered.  After all the input has been processed, print all of the values (with the number of occurrences) that were entered one or more times.
>   In addition, write a method that returns no value which would compute the average of the occurrences of all numbers entered by the user.

This is what I have (I have skipped the "average occurrence" part until I clean this up):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main 
{       
public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static int[] userIntegers()      // this method will build the array of integers, stopping when an out-of-range input is given
    {
            System.out.println("Enter the number of integers to be recorded:  ");
            int numInts = scan.nextInt();

            int[] userArray = new int[numInts];
            int i = 0;
            while(i < numInts)
            {
                    System.out.println("Enter an integer between 1-50 inclusive:  ");
                    int userInteger = scan.nextInt();
                    if(isValidInteger(userInteger))
                    {
                            userArray[i] = userInteger;
                            i++;
                    }
                    else if(isValidInteger(userInteger) == false)
                    {
                            System.out.println("Try again.");
                    }                       
            }
            return userArray;
    }

    public static void occurrenceOutput(int[] input)         // this method will print the occurrence data for a given array
    {   
        int[] occurrenceArray = new int[51];

            int j = 0;
            while(j < 51)  // iterates through all integers from 0 to 50, while the integer in the array is equal to integer j, the corresponding occurance array element increments.
            {
                    for(int eachInteger : input)
                    {
                            occurrenceArray[j] = (eachInteger == j)? occurrenceArray[j]+=1:  occurrenceArray[j];
                    }
                    j++;
            }               

            int k = 0;
            for(int eachOccurrence : occurrenceArray) // as long as there is more than one occurrence, the information will be printed.
            {
                    if(eachOccurrence > 1)
                    {
                            System.out.println("The integer " + k + " occurrs " + eachOccurrence + " times.");
                    }
                    k++;
            }
    }

    public static boolean isValidInteger(int userInput)     // checks if a user input is between 0-50 inclusive        
    {        
        boolean validInt = (51 >= userInput && userInput >= 0)?  true:  false;
            return validInt;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        occurrenceOutput(userIntegers());
    }
}
```

Can someone point me in a more elegant direction?

EDIT:  Thanks for the help!  This is where I am at now:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class simpleHist
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
            getUserInputAndPrint();
            getIntFreqAndPrint(intArray, numberOfInts);
    }

    private static int numberOfInts;
    private static int[] intArray;
    private static int[] intFreqArray = new int[51];

    public static void getUserInputAndPrint() 
    {
            //  The user is prompted to choose the number of integers to enter:
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the number of Integers:  ");
            numberOfInts = input.nextInt();

            //  The array is filled withchInteger = integer; integers ranging from 0-50:
            intArray = new int[numberOfInts];
            int integer = 0;
            int i = 0;
            while(i < intArray.length)
            {
                    System.out.println("Enter integer value(s):  ");
                    integer = input.nextInt();
                    if(integer > 50 || integer < 0)
                    {
                            System.out.println("Invalid input.  Integer(s) must be between 0-50 (inclusive).");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            intArray[i] = integer;
                            i++;
                    }
            }

            // Here the number of integers, as well as all the integers entered are printed:
            System.out.println("Integers: " + numberOfInts);    
            int j = 0;
            for(int eachInteger : intArray)
            {
                    System.out.println("Index[" + j + "] : " + eachInteger);
                    j++;
            }
    }

public static void getIntFreqAndPrint(int[] intArray, int numberOfInts)
{
    //  Frequency of each integer is assigned to its corresponding index of intFreqArray:
    for(int eachInt : intArray)
    {
        intFreqArray[eachInt]++;
    }

    //  Average frequency is calculated:
    int totalOccurrences = 0;
    for(int eachFreq : intFreqArray)
    {
        totalOccurrences += eachFreq;
    }
    double averageFrequency = totalOccurrences / numberOfInts;

    //  Integers occurring more than once are printed:
    for(int k = 0; k < intFreqArray.length; k++)
    {
        if(intFreqArray[k] > 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Integer " + k + " occurs " + intFreqArray[k] + " times.");
        }
            }

            //  Average occurrence of integers entered is printed:
            System.out.println("The average occurrence for integers entered is " + averageFrequency);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are actually looking for a [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram). You can implement it by using a [`Map<Integer,Integer>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), or since the range of elements is limited to 0-50, you can use an array with 51 elements [0-50], and increase `histogram[i]` when you read `i`.

Bonus: understanding this idea, and you have understood the basics of [count-sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort)

Comment: Wow we're totally histograms in my discrete class right now, that didn't even click.  The link on count-sorting was extremely helpful, thanks!

Comment: @obfuscater: I'm glad you are making this connection. You will soon enough realize that the math and theoretic classes you are taking will be a great asset for you as a programmer!

Answer (score 1):

To calculate occurences, you can do something like this:

```
 for(int eachInteger : input) {
      occurrenceArray[eachInteger]++;
 }
```

This will replace your while loop.

Comment: Dont feed answers to questions tagged homewotk

Comment: I had not thought of incrementing array elements that way, (have only been on arrays for a week).  Definitely easier on the eyes than what I had!